# how to send data from view activity to main activity? alternative to shared preferences or intents?

Tags: java, android

I have really backed myself into a corner. They only way I can access my data is from the view activity for my visualizer is in the view class. Any ideas on how I should go about this is strongly appreciated! cheers.

Comment: I have done at least 200 google searches lol.

Comment: Or if anyone could take the time to just tell me that it is not possible.

Comment: Has EventBus solved your problem? :)

Comment: It looked like a good solution. How ever I used a static variable to "magically" link the views. I need them connected contanstly for the life of the program so static shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Well I don't actually understand your app to be honest. You can send any kind of object with eventBus, make your own custom composite object and send it to anything! :D It's that easy

Answer (score 0):

If you're already ruling out SharedPrefs and Intents, a very nice 3rd party library comes to my mind: [Eventbus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus). It's great for this kind of thing, and it's quite easy to use.

Just check the docs and you'll have a lot of fun using this library. There's a tutorial on how to get started with it, and it's quite simple. **I've used it with great pleasure**.

**EDIT: (adding an example)**

First make a custom class of yours like (it can be very simple):

```
public class LoginErrorEvent {
    private int errorCode;

    public LoginErrorEvent(int errorCode) {
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
    }
}
```

This class can have as many fields of any type you'd like, but since you asked for int, let's say it has only 1 field which is int.

Now what you want to do in the place where you'd like to send the data:

```
eventBus.post(new LoginErrorEvent(errorCode));
```

Of course, you do need to follow the tutorial and initialize the EventBus in `onCreate` of an Activity/Fragment (`EventBus.getDefault();`)

All you now need to do is to listen for that event in the place you want to catch it by writing a method like this:

```
@Subscribe
public void onLoginErrorEvent(LoginErrorEvent loginErrorEvent){
    //your logic here, do whatever you wish with your int
    int errorCode = loginErrorEvent.getErrorCode();
    ........
    .....
}
```

> Keep in mind that name of the method does not have to be `onLoginErrorEvent`, it can be whatever like `foo`, but it's a good convention to follow giving a meaningful name like this. The only important thing about the method is that it has a parameter that is the type of the `Event` you're trying to catch.

Comment: Sweet I will give that go. Thank you.

Comment: You will not regret it. I've become an advocate for EventBus after having used it, that's how good it is. If it helps you with your particular task, consider accepting the answer.

Comment: Could you give me an idea of how I could transfer an integer variable with it from a java class? Its just a little hard for me to understand as I am just learning how to code. Thank you.

Comment: I've posted an example. This is literally the one from my project, only it is a bit simplified, but that's it basically.

Comment: I can't thank you enough for your kind input. App is working beautifully. Amazing how hard it is to find demonstrations for a newbie. Cheers!